# Will the value of a variable equal to an element of an array allocated on the heap change if the array is freed?

Tags: c, memory

If I have this code:

```
int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 9);
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   arr[i] = i;
}
int x = arr[1];
free(arr);
```

will x always be == to 1? or will it change?

Comment: No. Since `x` is not a pointer. Take a look at the instructions generated, https://godbolt.org/z/q7858sPWv.

Comment: You have multiple opposite questions. So the "No" in @alex01011 comment refers to "will it change". In case that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2):

`x` will not change no matter what you do to `arr`/`arr[1]` after the assignment. Assignment in C is by value; the value from `arr[1]` is read, and the result written to the storage for `x`, and after that, there is no relationship between `x` and `arr[1]`.

The only way you'd have a problem (as in undefined behavior, nasal demons sort of thing) is if you stored a pointer into the array and dereferenced it after the `free`, which would attempt to read from where the array used to be, and trigger undefined behavior.